# Mobile Web shows wrong Reputation earned in Recent Achievements

Tags: bug, reputation, mobile-web, mobile-safari

When I woke up this morning I saw the wrong reputation total in the "Recent Achievements" area.  33 rep was showing instead of the correct total of 35.

[image: Reputation]

I encountered this bug again this morning:

[image: Rep]

The second image is a low res upload from the Stack Exchange iOS app, but shows 18 reputation when 20 was earned.

- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)