# Incorrect Reputation Calculation in Achievements Dialog

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

The reputation gain shows +1, when I really gained +35.  Is this a timing bug?

[image: Achievements]

Potentially related: [Mobile Web shows wrong Reputation earned in Recent Achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284189/242209)

This is not a duplicate of [Recent achievements shows +1, but nothing listed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287651).  That question is about getting +1 back from deleted posts.  While this may have been the case, it does not explain the missing "new" rep gained.  As I understand it, the dialog should show +36 if that were the case.

Comment: Can you see if anything was deleted, such as an accepted answer with a +1?

Comment: My idea with this kind of notifications was always "someone upvoted me and then immediately unupvoted me". Not sure if that is the case here.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I figured it out, see my answer.  Just a funny order of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what happened.

[A question was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34971670/2415822) where I had a positively-scoring answer (+2 and an accept, for 35 reputation).  I also had downvoted one of the other answers (-1).

I had earned +35 rep this morning, but that rep was cancelled out by the -35 from the deleted post.  The only remaining rep was the +1 from the removal of the downvoted post, yielding a +1 net for the day so far.

[image: Reputation]

(the +10 for the `NSUserDefaults` question occurred after these events, and was not part of the original calculation of +1)

Not a bug, just an interesting order of events.