# Achievement icon shows different reputation than what was earned

Tags: bug, reputation, design, top-bar, achievements-dialog

The other day, I checked on my [recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341192/will-there-be-an-amazing-2019-stuff-a-way). To my surprise, the achievements icon displayed a different reputation change amount than what I had earned:

[image: The achievement icon with +6, but +8 was recently earned per the drop down menu.]

There is a discrepancy of 2, just as in [this very old, unanswered question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284189/mobile-web-shows-wrong-reputation-earned-in-recent-achievements).

My reputation total appears correct, but can we please get the discrepancy fixed?

**Edit**:

The next image, taken immediately after the first, shows the vote count. With 1 upvote and 1 downvote, the achievement icon could not have totaled +6:

[image: 1 upvote, 1 downvote]

**2nd Edit**:

Images of all my sites show no recent reputation changes, except MSE.

Stack Overflow:

[image: No recent rep changes]

Super User:

[image: No recent rep changes]

Software Engineering:

[image: No recent rep changes]

Code Review:

[image: No recent rep changes]

Code Golf:

[image: No recent rep changes]

Stack Apps:

[image: No recent rep changes]

Meta Stack Exchange:

[image: Rep changes today, Dec 29]

Comment: The icon shows from when you last looked. The dropdown shows today. Different criteria, different outcome.

Comment: @RobertLongson I updated my post.

Comment: Check if in other communities you're member a post where you had suggested an edit was deleted (you will lose the -2 rep you earned). Tick ['show removed posts'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRZ9W.png) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Something was deleted somewhere - it's impossible for us to find since it is not showing anywhere publicly. Anyway, no bug here, that's almost for sure.

Comment: @double-beep-ReinstateMonica My other sites show no changes. I’ve seen this bug before, but I haven’t reported it because I didn’t get the right images, and my other sites were active. Now I have the right images, and my other sites show no changes. It’ll take awhile, but I’ll edit again with images of my rep changes on other sites...

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard See the new images in my updated edit.

Comment: Still no bug, the only place showing rep change due to deleted posts is the reputation tab, with "show removed posts"  checkbox ticked.